# keyboard poping at a random height

Tags: objective-c, keyboard

I'd need your lights on an issue i just met.
I'm developing an ipad app and i have to use a datePicker to fill a textField.
To do so, for the desired textfield, i replace the usual keyboard by a datePicker using the **textField.inputView** property. More accurately, i do something like that:

```
UIDatePicker * datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

textField.inputView = datePicker;
```

, with datePickerValueChanged a method that enables to change the textfield.text value according to the datePicker chosen value.

When i tap any textfield, the keyboard (even the usual one) is displayed at a random height, sometimes covering the central part of the screen, sometimes the upper.
Could you help me solve this issue?